Can I apply nickel-plating to a galvanized steel pipe from Home Depot?
The piece is visible in the bathroom, and I'd like to improve the appearance by nickel-plating.
Will the nickel "stick" to galvanized steel, or should I get a brass pipe instead?

The zinc layer of galvanising is too reactive for nickel plating, but it can easily be striped off by the people doing the plating. They can then put a copper layer and then a nickel layer.
It might be easier to get a brass pipe,  there are nickel and chrome plated brass pipes available too I think.

Yup, the galvanized will serve as a temporary rust preventer just to get it from the factory to the plater.   Beats of getting a pipe covered in mill scale and rust.

either way step one at the platers is an acid bath, either to remove the patina or to remove the zinc
